# Invalid controller using custom routes

Tags: zend-framework

I've been following the instruction on how to create custom routes from the book [Zend Framework - A Beginners Guide](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JH_O_AaTi6IC&q=zend%20framework%20a%20beginner%27s%20guide&dq=zend%20framework%20a%20beginner%27s%20guide&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9HFuT-bEFYTF0QW_-v2MAg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA)

I've changed my `application.ini` file to include this routing information:

```
resources.router.routes.static-content.route = /content/:page
resources.router.routes.static-content.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.static-content.defaults.controller = static-content
resources.router.routes.static-content.defaults.view = static-content
resources.router.routes.static-content.defaults.action = display
```

Given the above configuration, I have this controller:

```
<?php

class Default_StaticContentController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function displayAction()
    {
        // action body
        $page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page');
        if (file_exists($this->view->getScriptPath(null) . 
                '/' . $this->getRequest()->getControllerName() . '/' .
                $page . $this->viewSuffix
                )) {
            $this->render($page);
        }
        else {
            throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('HLC - Page not found', 404);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a view named `about.phtml` in the APPLICATION_PATH/modules/default/views/static-content folder.

What ahppens is I get an error saying:

```
An error occurred

Page not found

Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller class ("StaticContentController")

Stack trace:

#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(262): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->loadClass('StaticContentCo...')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zend/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zend/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/HLC/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#5 {main}  
Request Parameters:

array (
  'page' => 'about',
  'module' => 'default',
  'controller' => 'static-content',
  'view' => 'static-content',
  'action' => 'display',
)
```

Note that it is not rendering my customised `Zend_Controller_Action_Exception` but throwing the global error.

I'm using the URL: http://hlc.local:8888/content/about

The default index action works ok, just this routing that's not working.

Comment: I think you have problem with your view, it should be display.phtml

Comment: Well, it should be routing to about.phtml as the controller uses the `:page` parameter to find the correct view file. So it should be about.phtml

Comment: @haltabush can you mark it as answer if AlexW got the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are actually following the book closely, you have an extra line in your route declaration and your controller class should be `StaticContentController`.

here is the route definition from the book that does work.

```
resources.router.routes.static-content.route = /content/:page
resources.router.routes.static-content.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.static-content.defaults.controller = static-content
resources.router.routes.static-content.defaults.action = display
```

I still have this code laying around from last summer.

I found this book less then satisfactory and not really for beginners. It fails to address the Zend_Db component opting instead to introduce Doctrine 1.2. It's seems to be a trend that a number of these beginner/easy books feel that a full ORM is more useful then Zend_Db. If you are already familiar with Doctrine this approach works fine, otherwise it's a lot to ask of a beginner, to learn ZF and Doctrine at the same time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're right, I have added a line for view for some reason... Was late last night when I did this. Will check it in a short while... thanks for the tip.

Comment: Unfortunately after updating the application.ini file, it still fails. Exactly the same error occurs, except this time the request params array contains no `view` file name. Thanks all the same.

Comment: did you take the "Default" off of `Default_StaticContentController`?

Comment: You're bang-on @RockyFord, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now what you use for autoloading. so that would helpful to determine.so far I understand your class named should be something like this ModulePath_ApplicationPath_ControllerName, so its Default_Application_StaticContentController.

and for better routing I preferred [zend manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/). you can try this [tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) for route. it would help for you.